# Set startup page in Windows 8 application

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-8

I create new project for Windows Store (C#) from template Split App (XAML) and I want to change Startup page from ItemsPage.xaml to SplitPage.xaml. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Open App.xaml.cs
2. Search for `if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(ItemsPage), "AllGroups"))`
3. Change `ItemsPage` to whichever page you want to open first, in your case `SplitPage`.